# Modify URL Before It Is Loaded On Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, script, youtube, url, tampermonkey

Every time I load a YouTube video, I find myself first appending `&hd=1` to the end of the URL so that the video plays in HD automatically. Over time, this gets annoying, so I would like it to be done automatically.

How can I automatically append `&hd=1` to the end of a URL beginning with `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=`?

### More Information

- My OS is Ubuntu Gnome 13.04
- I am using Google Chrome 32.0.1700.77 as my default browser

### Answer

I was lucky enough to find [this](https://userscripts.org/scripts/show/124528) [Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) script, which I was then able to load with [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo/reviews?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) and which seems to do the job.

Comment: I would recommend that you look into the extension Youtube Center, it has a lot of functionality, among others setting default resolution.

Comment: Please *always* include your OS. Solutions very often depend on the Operating System being used. Are you using Unix, Linux, BSD, OSX, something else? Which version?

Comment: @Martin Could you please provide a link? I looked up Youtube Center and found [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-center/gabnjlibfmlilpljjkkbkebfaopgpjmk?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon), which is not what you specified.

Comment: Youtube Center: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/114002
Scroll down till you see your Chrome, cannot be installed via Chrome Webstore. If I remeber correctly you have to download to desktop and drag it into a chrome window.

Comment: @Martin Sadly, that doesn't seem to work. It may have something with YouTube being HTTPS by default, but I don't want to have to change the URL every time.

Comment: hmm, I could've sworn it used to work, probably some recent change from youtube, all the other functions I use from YTC works fine.

Comment: @dillmo could you post your own solution as an answer instead of including it into the question?

Comment: [Script link](https://userscripts.org/scripts/show/124528) is dead as of 2023